# Variance and Covariance Expectations in 2-Level Model with Random slope & intercept

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, multilevel-analysis, covariance, nested-models

**1. Could you provide an example of how to hypothesize the variance and covariance expectations for a multi-level model with random slopes and random intercepts?**

I do not yet have access to my data, so I am unsure how to write the model formula to determine the E[Var] and E[Cov].

I am learning about mixed-effect modeling and need help with developing a hypothesis for the variance. My data will include country, demographic information, region, and a likert scale opinion question to model a metric of poverty.

I plan to use a random slope and random intercept model due to the potential cross-level interactions. A professor has requested that I write up my variance hypotheses for the model. He asked for the variance and covariance expectations at the second level (country).

I don't have access to the data yet and am unsure how to write the variance and covariance expectations. While we've set a list of potential variables, I do not yet know which will be included in the model formula. Since I don't have the model formula or access to the data, I feel unsure of how to write out the variance and covariance expectations.

Thank you!

Comment: A common way in a situation like this is to search for published studies that have a similar (or close) design as in your intended study and base your variance component estimates on these studies' variance components.